# How to download video in background HTML5 / JS

Tags: javascript, html, video

Is there a way to make a video download in the background (Possible on a different thread?) than I get my images and do webrequests?

Situation:

I show a video, video plays fine. 
But, once I start getting 2 images at the same time from that server, the page won't response and will wait for my video to have finished loading, then it loads the images within a few seconds. (about 100kb per image).

If I try to open any other page on the same browser and the crashed page's server it won't load untill the crashed page is done loading, however any other site(For example google) will just load fine.

So is there a way to make the browser not want to download full video, or maybe just give priority to images?

Comment: don't inline the video, add it right after the page loads so as to not stall the image loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the server throttling your requests, as everything apart from scripts always load asynchronously in a browser.

It might be that you are only allowed so much bandwidth per second from the server - or so many connections - and that could be the reason why the server won't respond until your first request has finished.

Check your server configuration and perhaps have a play with it to exclude this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a worker, it provides a way to execute background scripts (you will have to split your video and images in separate files), as you can see in the Use Cases it refers to "Prefetching and/or caching data for later use" as a possible scenario. Hope it helps.

More info here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-examples